# PowerShell PGP Encryption Hangs

Tags: powershell, gnupg, pgp

I've got a seemingly simple task.  Encrypt a text file before sending to a vendor via SFTP.  They require the file be encrypted using PGP and a Public key file they have provided us.  We will be using PowerShell. I have searched for two days for a solution, and tried multiple approaches. We've gotten closest with a third-party app named `[GPG4Win][1]`.  Unfortunately, the documentation is poor and examples are few.

Thru trial and error, this is what I've come up with.  Using a command line, I added the provided public key to our "KeyRing".  So when I type in the command gpg --list-key, I get his result.
[image]

The script I'm executing is this, but it simply gets to the line where I call the gpg4winapp and it hangs indefinitely.  I have tried a few different options but always end up with some type of generic error.

```
$gpg4winApp = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}" + "\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe"
$workingPath = "D:\Concur\TestWorkingPath\"
$destination = "$($workingPath)Encrypted\"


$nameGen = New-Object -TypeName EncryptedFileNameGenerator
$fileToEncrypt = $($workingPath) + "TestFile1.txt"
$outputFile = $($destination) + "encryptedFile"
Write-Host "Encrypting file " + $fileToEncrypt + " as " $outputFile
& $gpg4winApp -e -o $encryptedFileName $fileToEncrypt 
Write-Host "File encrypted"
```

Comment: Have you tried "Hi, third party, just so as we are sure to maintain compatibility, could you let us know which tool you'd like us to use for PGP encryption? And have you got a sample script so we're all on the same page?"

Comment: Yes, that was my first thought too and I tried.  They seem to be of the opinion the PGP encryption is something that is natively available everywhere and that they don't recommend or prefer any tool for PGP encryption.

Comment: Does your code work in a PowerShell window where you type one command at a time?

Comment: Can [this](https://4sysops.com/archives/encrypt-and-decrypt-files-with-powershell-and-pgp/) be of help?